# Pre-ticking checkboxes in Angular2

Tags: angular

I'm using RC7. I want to pre-populate some checkboxes, but can't find an answer that works for me.

basically I have this

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.price = [true, true, false];
  }
```

and have tried to use ngModel and `checked` to turn on 2 of the 3 checkboxes

```
<label *ngFor="let val of prices; let i = index" class="radio-inline">
  {{val.name}}
  <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="price[i]" [checked]="price[i]" name="price">
</label>
```

But none of the checkboxes are checked at the end of bootstrapping. If I click on them then the correct values are available in `this.price` in the component.

**Update:** Likewise

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="price[i]" [value]="price[i]" name="price">
```

does not work.

**Answer**
I got the best result combining the two answers below, by using ngModel but with the boolean value stored in the iterable.

```
<label *ngFor="let val of prices" class="radio-inline">
  {{val.name}}
  <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="val.state" name="price" />
</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below,

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>
  <label *ngFor="let val of prices; let i = index" class="radio-inline">
  {{val.name}}
  <input type="checkbox" [checked]="val" name="price">
</label>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  prices=[];
   ngOnInit() {
    this.prices = [true, true, false];
  }
}
```

Here is the [Plunker!!](http://plnkr.co/edit/158EXln1bKE8QHIuaScu?p=preview)

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
[checked]="price[i]"
```

assign the initial value to

```
price[i]
```

then `[(ngModel)]="price[i]` will update the state of the checkbox

Comment: May have misunderstood you, but tried using `[value]` and that did not work either - see updated question

Comment: I didn't write anything about `[value]`. I don't understand what you mean. When the `prices` you iterate over using `*ngFor` contain `true` or `false` the checkbox will be checked or not by `[(ngModel)]="price[i]`